# Exclude jar from war Maven 3

Tags: war, maven-3, weblogic-10.x

We need to exclude few jars from war ...we are using maven 3 in weblogic.

I tried

```
<packagesourceexludes>...and <warsournceexludes..>
```

but didn't work.

Any other way to do this.

Thanks
Vijay

Comment: Would be good to know what you have tried and why you need to exclude them form your war...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>xerces</groupId>
  <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

So doesn't need to exclude from every dependency..
This solved my problem...Thanks for all your answer...

Comment: The secret is the **scope** tag that we should declare it to **provided**.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `<packagingExcludes>` as documented [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html).  Cut/pasting the example for reference...

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to exclude dependencies is shown [here](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Exclusions). If that's what you've tried, make sure, no other dependency includes the excluded jar (which can be checked by mvn dependency:tree).