# How do I tell maven that an artifact has been renamed?

Tags: java, maven

Consider the following scenario.

I have a Java 1.8 project that depends on a java 8 artifact called `foo-bar` and a java 5 artifact called `baz-qux`. `baz-qux` also depends on `foo-bar`. But it uses the special slimmed down java 5 build called `foo-bar-java5`. Thus by including `baz-qux` into my project, I transitively bring in `foo-bar-java5`. In the end I have an undesirable state where I now have `foo-bar` and `foo-bar-java5`. Apparently there's no way to do a global exclude. So I can't just exclude `foo-bar-java5`. Instead, I must clutter up my cluttered pom and exclude it everywhere it will be pulled in transitively.

With that said, is there any way I can specify that `foo-bar` provides `foo-bar-java5`? Or is the only option to truly exclude `foo-bar-java5` everywhere?

Comment: Can you not version it differently? `foo:bar:1.0` and `foo:bar:1.0-java5`?  Or do you have no control over that?

Comment: You could have the two different dependencies in a profile, but that is generally not a good idea. I would go the simple way and provide a seperate Java 5 POM, especially since you can than forget about it and never touch it again :)

Comment: You can declare foo-bar-java5 explicitly in <provided> scope. Then it will not be included in list of runtime jars.

Comment: foo-bar and foo-bar-java5 is a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer from another question that may work for you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9623517/2879838

Basically, explicitly list the foo-bar-java5 as a dependency in your project and list it as provided.  This will tell maven not to put that jar into the archive during the build.  This should be a lot less messier than excluding it everywhere.

Comment: afaik, mvn eclipse:eclipse will still bring in a provided dependency.

Comment: Correct, your IDE will pull in the lib as a dependency, but the archive build will exclude the lib.  If you need your IDE to not have the lib pulled down into your project, then, yeah, I would say you need to explicitly exclude it everywhere in your pom.xml